# Allow Google App Engine app access to only one Cloud SQL Instance database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a few small Google App Engine apps that are accessing the same Cloud SQL Instance (to save resources) and I wan't to restrict the access of these individual databases per app; eg.

```
1. CoolApp5 ---> global_db_instance -> coolapp5_db
2. EatFood ----> global_db_instance -> eatfood_db
3. WebsiteCo --> global_db_instance -> websiteco_db
```

[Configuring Google Could SQL Instance Access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control)

The current system seems to allow for apps to have access to the global instance databases but creates a security vulnerability. If a intruder get's access to the database true a single app (coolapp5/eatfood or websiteco) he will have access to the **all** the databases.

**Eg. Wordpress sites for CoolApp5**

```
<?php // wp-config.php 
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/global_db_instance:db'); //
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'coolapp5_db');
?>
```

As you can see, the app `coolapp5` has access to `coolapp5_db` and could gain access other database (`eatfood_db, websiteco_db`) as the app has root access.

[Google seems to allow this through an external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess)

An obvious solution might be to have many individual instance for each app, but this is inefficient for small apps as a Cloud SQL database can run multiple websites at once.

Is there any other solution or is my strategy simply will not work for Google Cloud SQL ?

Answer (score 3):

Setup MySQL users per database/application ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html)) within your single Cloud SQL instance and grant access to these new users to only the database they need.

Comment: Can you slightly elaborate? I do not have an IPv4 address to make the mysql changes, can I temporary enable this feature, add the users and disable it, or is my apps now need to connect true the ipv4 with the new user accounts, to access the mysql instance?

Comment: Your hostname does not need to change, you only have to create users ```CREATE USER 'app1_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';```and grant that user access to only his db ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON app1_db.* TO 'app1_user'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;```